# Cannot use App\Models\Mission as Mission because the name is already in use

Tags: laravel

I have used the Mission model as:

use App\Models\Mission;

and it's located there for sure, locally it's working fine and no errors occur. But, on the staging environment it shows the error above. any command I should run on the staging environment ? . I have tried: php artisan optimize:clear but problem persist to occur

Error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fy1Cj.png)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\ServiceProvider;

use App\DataTables\ProjectDataTable;
use App\Http\Requests\CreateProjectRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateProjectRequest;
use App\Models\Project;
use App\Notifications\ProjectStatusChanged;
use App\Repositories\ProjectRepository;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Flash;
use App\Http\Controllers\AppBaseController;
use App\Models\Mission;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Illuminate\Routing\Redirector;
use Illuminate\View\View;
use Response;

class ProjectController extends AppBaseController
{
    /** @var  ProjectRepository */
    private $projectRepository;

    /**
     * ProjectController constructor.
     * @param ProjectRepository $projectRepo
     */
    public function __construct(ProjectRepository $projectRepo)
    {
        $this->projectRepository = $projectRepo;
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the Project.
     *
     * @return View
     * @throws AuthorizationException
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->authorize('viewAny', Project::class);

        $perPage = request('per-page', 5);

        $search = request('search');

        $projects = Project::orderByDesc('created_at')
            ->where('service_provider_id', Auth::user()->service_provider->id)
            ->search($search)
            ->paginate($perPage);

        return view('projects.index', compact('projects'));
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified Project.
     *
     * @param $slug
     *
     * @return Application|RedirectResponse|Redirector
     * @throws AuthorizationException
     */
    public function show($slug)
    {
        $project = $this->projectRepository->findBySlug($slug);
        $allSites = collect();
        $sitesIds = []; //to prevent duplicate sites
        $missionsCompleted = $project->missions->where('status', '!=' , Mission::STATUS_COMPLETED)->count() ? false : true;

        foreach ($project->missions as $mission) { //store all project's site in an array
            if (in_array($mission->site->id, $sitesIds))
                continue;
            array_push($sitesIds, $mission->site->id);
            
            $allSites->push($mission->site);
        }

        $this->authorize('view', $project);

        if (empty($project)) {
            Flash::error('Project not found');

            return redirect(route('projects.index'));
        }

        return view('projects.show')->with([
            'project'=>$project,
            'allSites'=>$allSites,
            'missionsCompleted'=>$missionsCompleted,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  open the file that the error came from (check your laravel.log) and the copy/paste your `uses` section from that file. Paste the stacktrace from your error, it will help determine what's wrong

Comment: If you post the related code to this error, we would confirm to you that you are giving the alias `Mission` to two classes and would help you improve your code. So add the code (including the `use`s) to your question.

Comment: Checkout: [Fatal error: Cannot declare class Error, because the name is already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52301800/fatal-error-cannot-declare-class-error-because-the-name-is-already-in-use) and [Cannot declare class x, because the name is already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73725902/cannot-declare-class-x-because-the-name-is-already-in-use)

Comment: [PHP: cannot declare class because the name is already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42682501/php-cannot-declare-class-because-the-name-is-already-in-use)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Cannot declare class because the name is already in use in (same file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65748119/cannot-declare-class-because-the-name-is-already-in-use-in-same-file)

Comment: Share your Model source code as well: *'App\Models\Mission'*.

Comment: The code you show is the one in your local installation that doesnt have the issue. i'm guessing that you're using GIT (or another versioning tool) and a conflict was resolved badly and now you have two `use Xxx/Xxx/Mission;` in the controller. you can check your git for this or give your class another alias as @AliRaza suggested.

Comment: You can notice that the error is on line 16 while in your file, the line use `use App\Models\Mission;` is on line 15. on your staging server the file has an extra line that also calls for `use Xxx\Xxx\Mission;` maybe event the same class.

Answer (score 3):

Use alias in namespace:

```
use App\Models\Mission as MyMission;
```